# When is viewDidLoad called in a container environment?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, autolayout, uicontainerview

My situation looks like the following:

I have different container views. If the user triggers a tap event I create a new container and call a method on it, which sets the content of a child view controller. The problem I head was that the object (`UIWebView` in my case) was nat available at that time. The reason is that `viewDidLoad` hasn't been called at that time and the webview wasn't set up. Now I moved the initialisation of the webview in the constructor. This leads to my second issue:

On another container I load the same child view controller (with the web view on it). Because the bounds of the view are not available in the constructor I switched to auto layout. Now auto layout couldn't be applied because there was no superview. The cause of the issue was that `viewDidLoad` of the child view was called (where I set up my constraints) before it has been added to the container view. So there was no superview available regardles where I tried it to add as child view controller. Then I moved my auto layout setup into `updateViewConstraints` which works.

Now I'm wondering when `viewDidLoad` will be called. I cannot assume right after the initialization of the view controller, because that's not true. How could I reliable pass data to my child view controller when it's ready? Am I doing something wrong here?

When will `viewDidLoad` be called? Sometimes it is called right after initialization and sometimes not ...

Comment: Instead of trying to set data when the child is ready, set it to the child and make it use the data when it's ready (i.e in the viewDidLoad)

Comment: You're right. I changed my code. What I also changed is, that I wanted to call a method which displays my content at all times. Because I did this for displaying the content when the web view was already loaded (first container) and also right after initializing the web view (second container) I got my nil error. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)The view controller calls `loadView` method when its `view` property is requested but is currently nil.
2)After view is created view controller calls `viewDidLoad` method.
3)`view` property return created view

Summarising: `viewDidLoad`  method called during first time you are requesting `view` property

Comment: Because I didn't accessed the `view` property it wasn't loaded at that time. An ugly workaround would be to access the view property right after initialization. But thanks to *Imotep* I restructured my code and now it doesn't matter when `viewDidLoad` is exactly called. Thanks for your clarification.